# Public transport from/to Rhodes Airport

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, car-rentals, greece, rho

I am planning a trip to Rhodes (Greece) and looking for the best deal for renting a car.

I have found that the best deal is to get the car on daytime. If I take the car on daytime is the half as if I do it on night time and, unfortunately, my flight arrives and depart late.

The sensible option is to travel to the airport next day to take the car but Google doesn't have information about public transport from [Kolympia to Rhodes Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Rodos+International+Airport,+Paradeisi,+Greece/Kolympia,+Greece/@36.3376067,28.0739271,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x14957b67c99e7011:0x5e4f87c20b3a1a8f!2m2!1d28.09022!2d36.402288!1m5!1m1!1s0x14956e60f00ced99:0xdd740c6df7d18d6a!2m2!1d28.1437395!2d36.2576048). I also checked the [Tourism information page](http://www.visitrhodes.gr/showcontent.asp?id=19&mainid=6) but the don't say anything about fares or times.

Does anybody know where I can get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This website](http://www.ando.gr/eng), which appears to be from the Dodecanese Economic Development agency, includes tourist info in English, including a bus schedule.  To get from Kolympia to Rhodes you would presumably take a bus run by the [KTEL company](http://www.ktelrodou.gr/) from Kolymbia Beach, which runs

> RHODES-KOLYMBIA BEACH: 09.00-12.00*-14.00*-14.30-15.00-16.00-17.30-19.30-21.15-23.00
>
> KOLYMBIA BEACH-RHODES: 09.00-10.00-10.30-11.30-12.25*-13.30-15.00-16.00-16.25-18.15-20.10
>
> PRICE:  3.90€ ONE WAY

(Starred routes do not run on Saturdays.)  The timetable can also be found on [KTEL's website.](http://www.ktelrodou.gr/dromologia/kathemerina.html)

You would then take the bus from Rhodes to the airport, using RODA, the Rhodes municipal bus company (can't find a webpage, sorry):

> RHODES-PARADISSI(air port): 04.45-05.20*-06.30**-06.45**-07.10-07.30-08.15**-08.30-09.00-09.30-10:00-10:30-11:15**-11.30-
>   12.00-12:30-13.00-13.15**-13:30-14.00-14.30-15.15*-15:45-16:00-16.30-16.50*-17.30-18:00-18:30-19.00*-20:00-20.30*-21:00-22.00-
>   22:30
>
> PARADISSI (airport)- RHODES: 06.40-07.25**-07.55***-08.15-09.00-09.20-09.55-10:15-10:45-11.15-12.10-12.30**-12:40-13:15-
>   13.45-14.15-14.50-15.00**-15:40-16.05-16:45-17.15-17.25*-17.45-18:15-18:45-19.35*-19:45-20.20*-21:05*-21.15-21:45-22.20*-23.00-
>   23.15
>
> PRICE: 2.50€ One Way  FROM DRIVER: 2.60€ One way.

Here, a single star means the bus doesn't go down the coast beyond the airport;  two stars mean no Saturday service;  three stars mean *only* Saturday service.  The above link also contains a Sunday/holiday schedule for this bus line.